# Any url that starts with the pattern.. do this

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to compare url A (`http://www.somehost.com/citizenship`) with the pattern url B (`http://www.somehost.com/*`) and if that URL A starts with the pattern url B then do this thing.. As URL A is originated from the URL B.. So any url that starts with this pattern.. just do this thing in the if loop... Any suggestions will be appreciated...!!

```
BufferedReader readbuffer = null;
        try {
            readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filters.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String strRead;


        try {
            while ((strRead=readbuffer.readLine())!=null){
                String splitarray[] = strRead.split(",");
                String firstentry = splitarray[0];
                String secondentry = splitarray[1];
                String thirdentry = splitarray[2];
                //String fourthentry = splitarray[3];
                //String fifthentry = splitarray[4];
                System.out.println(firstentry + " " + secondentry+ " " +thirdentry);
                URL url1 = new URL("http://www.somehost.com/citizenship");

 //Any url that starts with this pattern then do whatever you want in the if loop... How can we implement this??                    
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://www.somehost.com/*");

                Matcher m = p.matcher(url1.toString());

                if (m.matches()) {
                  //Do whatever
                    System.out.println("Yes Done");
                }



                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: My regex is rusty, but at first glance, it appears your pattern does not allow for anything after the wireless-reach portion.   Shouldn't it end with some sort of wildcard matching symbol as well?

Comment: @Sparky, Means what kind of wildcard symbols.. Can you tell with some example? What I want is that any URL that starts with the URL B.. then do this.. So in the above case url `http://www.somehost.com/citizenship/wireless-reach/news-and-resources` is from this pattern only `http://www.somehost.com/.*/wireless-reach` So any url that starts with this pattern.. just do this thing in the if loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with [`String.startsWith(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)?

You could invoke it like this: `url1.toString().startsWith("http://www.somehost.com/")`.

Or did I miss what you're exactly trying to achieve?

Anyways, this is the regular expression to build: `http://www\.somehost\.com/.*`

You need to learn regular expression syntax, in which "." mean any character so you need to escape it in between "www" and "somehost".

In Java code, you need to escape backspaces as well hence it becomes: `Pattern.compile("http://www\\.somehost\\.com/.*");`

Comment: Main thing is that, I have list of URL patterns in a text file and I am opening that file to get the pattern URL. So in that file first pattern is `http://www.somehost.com/*` and here * is the wildcard. So Any URL which starts with this pattern of wildcard.. do this...So I cannot do this `url1.toString().startsWith(splitArray[0])`..

Comment: then you need to analyze what comes from your config file and construct a pattern from it. and you would replace `*` by `.*` so that your wildcard is turned into "any character, zero or more times"

Comment: @Raihan Do the patterns you read from the file syntactically conform to regular expressions?

Comment: @WindsurferOak, They are not conform to regular expressions.. They have * as the wild card only...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
    private final static String regexPattern = "http://www.somehost.com/[0-9a-zA-Z\\-]*/wireless-reach(/[0-9a-zA-Z\\-]*)*";
    String pattern = "http://www.somehost.com/citizen-ship/wireless-reach/fil1";

    if(pattern.matches(regex))
         System.out.println("Matched!");
```

Comment: I have updated the question.. I don't understand what you just said above... I don't want to match.. I want any URL that starts with the URL Pattern... then do this.. just like startsWith method in JAVA..

Comment: This regex pattern above would have matched your original pattern. It seems that you are working with multiple patterns. Is that correct?